# Avoiding N+1 Queries on Actiontext::RichText of an included table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, actiontext

My data is set up like this:
a Chat has_many messages
a Message has_rich_text :detail_html

Anyhow, I am trying to do a query that returns all the Chats. That query looks something like this:

```
Chat.all.includes(:messages)
```

However, because of ActionText, I'm noticing that I still have an N+1 query which makes sense. I've seen stuff like Message.all.with_rich_text_meal_details which works but the issue is that I'm not query the table with the has_rich_text, instead I'm querying a related table. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> scope :"with_rich_text_#{name}", -> { includes("rich_text_#{name}") }

From [source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/6efe2b490083c90550786ab70957e8dc548baf23/actiontext/lib/action_text/attribute.rb#L45), there's an implicit relationship `has_one rich_text_*` with the `Model` added `has_rich_text`. In your case, `Message has_one rich_text_meal_details`.

So you could try to eager loading `meal_details` by:

```rb
Chat.all.includes(messages: :rich_text_meal_details)
```